# bootcode.bin RPi 3

Tags: operating-systems, bare-metal, assembly

I've been reading this document:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/bootflow.md

About the boot process of the Raspberry Pi. I want to make a simple "Hello, World!" operating system in AArch64 assembly and was wondering what the entry point was in the bootcode.bin file? I've never done any operating system programming before and certainly never on the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I thought using a Raspberry Pi would be easier to learn with compared to using an Intel x86_64 computer.

Do I just create a main function as I would if I was programming in C?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=72&t=201556) and the other resources in the [Bare metal, Assembly forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewforum.php?f=72) are a great start.

Comment: @Cromulent no problem, let us know how it goes